# Cursor Exception thrown in PHP with empty MongoDB aggregation

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB 2.6.1 and the latest MongoDB PHP driver to perform an aggregation query. When I loop through the CommandCursor returned using foreach it works fine, however if the aggregation does not return any results, then the foreach loop throws a Cursor Exception.

Is there a better way of handling this other than try/catch of a MongoCursor exception?

My collection has a datetime field, stored as a "proper timestamp" so it can be easily queried. I know that I have no data before 2014-05-25, but data for every day after that. In the simplest aggregation that I can get to fail with an error, I have just a match stage:

I call the cursor by:

```
$connection = MongoClient(<connection string>);
$collection = $connection->test->testColl;

$dateFrom = new MongoDate(strtotime("2014-05-15"));
$dateTo = new MongoDate(strtotime("2014-05-24"));

$query = array(array('$match' =>
                 array(
                      'timestamp' => array('$gt' => $dateFrom, '$lt' => $dateTo)
                      )
               )
         );

$results = $collection->aggregateCursor($query);

foreach ($results as $item)
{
    // do stuff with row, e.g.
    var_dump($item);
}
```

If I change $dateFrom and $dateTo to dates where there is valid data, I can iterate happily over the data without any exceptions. When I have no data return, PHP returns the following error:

```
Exception: mongodbserver.local:27017 : assertion src/mongo/s/cursors.cpp:262
File: </path/to/php/file>
Line: <line number of the foreach loop>

Exception Stack Trace
#0 </path/to/php/file>(<line number of the foreach loop>): MongoCommandCursor->rewind()
#1 {main}
```

Comment: Please provide some code demonstrating your current approach.

Comment: What is in your aggregate pipeline, what's the collection you're querying, what's the message in the exception?

Comment: You seem to be getting an assertion from the *server*. The PHP driver doesn't have "src/mongo/s/cursors.cpp", but the server does. In this case mongos. What sort of set-up do you have? Do you use sharding? Can you describe your set-up?